# Paste table name as parameter

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, ado.net

I want to paste table name as function parameter and function need to return DataSet, this is the my code for that:

```
 Public Function GetTTabele(ByVal tableName As String) As DataSet
        Dim DAT As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT *  FROM tableName", nwindConn)
        Dim DAT  As DataSet = New DataSet()
        DAT.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey
        DAT.Fill(DAT, tableName)
        GetTTabele = DAT 
    End Function
```

Now when i execute this code I'm getting next error:
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 'tableName'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"SELECT *  FROM tableName"

should be changed to "SELECT *  FROM " & tableName

allowing the contents of your parameter *tableName* to be appended to the string "SELECT *  FROM "

Answer (score 0):

Table "tableName" does not exists on your database. Specify a existing table name.

Comment: I paste in function name of table that exists in database!

GetTTabele(Orders)

Comment: But currently you are passing the string tableName, instead of the variable string tableName. See nicholas answer

Answer (score 0):

Change the line of code

```
 Dim DAT As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT *  FROM tableName", nwindConn)
```

to read

```
 Dim DAT As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT *  FROM " & tableName, nwindConn)
```

You are trying to find a table called, literally, "tableName", rather than the table name **stored in the variable** tableName.